# Easy set partition problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

So I have this problem :

Let **A** be a non empty set an **P1** and **P2** be two random partitions of the set **A**. Prove that the set [image] is also a partition of **A**.

I know that this is probably very easy to most of you but discrete mathematics isn't my strong side so basically i have no idea. All help is well welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really all you need to do is to verify that the three axioms of a partition holds for $\cal S$.

1. $\varnothing\notin\cal S$. That's trivial by the definition.
2. $A=\bigcup\cal S$, or for every $a\in A$ there is some $Z\in\cal S$ such that $a\in Z$. But recall that $P_1$ and $P_2$ were partitions. You can find $X\in P_1, Y\in P_2$ which include $a$, and so $Z$ must be...?
3. Every two distinct sets in $\cal S$ are disjoint. This is not hard either, $(X_1\cap Y_1)\cap(X_2\cap Y_2)=(X_1\cap X_2)\cap(Y_1\cap Y_2)=\ldots$